# Convert NSDate from string

Tags: ios6

I'm displaying an NSDate stored in core data into a UITextField so the user can edit it.
I'm using NSDateFormatter to format the date into "dd-MM-yyyy" format, which works fine.

When the user presses save, i want to convert this string back into a date and update the core data record, which is fine, but i also want to convert it to a different format.

So from 15-01-2004 to 2004-01-15

This is what i have

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
[formatter2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

[urlParams appendFormat:@"&DOB=%@", [formatter2 stringFromDate:date]];
```

The problem i'm having is i'm getting the date back as 2004-00-15 instead of 2004-01-15

I'm obviously misunderstanding something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
```

to

```
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

mm is minutes